# CGPathRef and PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, core-graphics

It there a way to draw a complex shape with an application like CorelDraw or Adobe Flash, etc, save it or export it as a PDF and then open it with Core Graphics in iOS.
The idea is, to draw a shape, a vector, with CorelDraw - for example, and it is just the path. No color or fill. And then be able to open it directly by Core Graphics, add it as a CGPath to the context, and then be able to manipulate it, like fill it with solid color or gradient, or patterns.

The bottom line is, I am looking for a way to draw a complex shape in a user-friendly environment, like Corel or Flash, and export it, as a vactor, which can be manipulated in Core Graphics. And suggestions or help is really appreicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVGKit doesn't work the exact same as I need either. Although I should say it is nicely done. There are also other resources, that I found and I'll leave them here for future references, if anyone stops by this post and is looking for a solution.

[Converting SVG Paths to Objective-C Paths](http://ponderwell.net/2011/05/converting-svg-paths-to-objective-c-paths/) Good for simple paths; strokes and fills can be manipulated later by using protocols. Complex paths get mixed up.

[SVGKit](https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit) Good for creating images and animate them later through the course of the program. However, strokes, fills, paths can not be manipulated.

[Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) You can export as source code, hence you have more control over strokes, paths, and fills. As the path gets more complex, it is harder to manage the code manually. The other problem is by the time of export, the program adds resolution-dependent codes. It can be a pain to go through about 300+ lines of code to fix it so that it is not resolution dependent. By the final product wouldn't be mixed up, and can be manipulated by protocols. Layers are CGLayers, not CALayers.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you've got PDF files (from Corel, or another app), you can display them using CoreGraphics.

Take a look at the:

- [CGPDFDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) class
- [CGPDFPage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFPage/Reference/reference.html) class

Then, there is a [CGContextDrawPDFPage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawPDFPage) function, that you can use to draw a PDF pages in a given graphic context, typically in the `drawLayer: inContext:` method of a UIView subclass.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of those methods. That's not exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to add path references from within a PDF file to a CGContext, while preserving their CGPath attributes. Those methods basically draw the PDF and the drawn PDF does not respond to functions such as CGContextFillRect, etc.

Comment: Yep, but you need to use the context passed to the `drawLayer:inContext:` method. It's just an instance of `CGContextRef`, so it should respond... First draw the PDF page on the context, then modify the context to suit your needs.

Comment: It doesn't work. Try it this way: (1) draw a circle in Flash or Corel -- no fill, just stroke, (2) save it / export it as PDF, (3) add it to your Xcode project resources, (4) open it as a CGPDFDocument, get the first page and draw it to a context (CGLayer or UIGraphics, doesn't make a difference) (5) call CGContextFillRect (context); --- if it does what I am looking for, you should get a circle, filled with black color. But it doesn't happen, because the CGPDFPage drawn to the context does not behave as a path. I wish it would.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a built-in way to load `CGPath`s from files but you might want to take a look at [SVGKit](https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit). Pretty much every modern vector drawing app can produce SVG files.

Comment: It looks compelling. I'll give it a shot. Thanks.